# OpenGL cubemap reflections flipping with moving camera

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping

I am testing a basic cubemap implementation and it works fine except one last detail.
When I move my camera the cubemap flips on the up/down axis.

As I move the camera, notice my view matrix when the flipping happens:

```
------
 0.01,  0.13, -0.99,  0.00
 0.00,  0.99,  0.13,  0.00
 1.00, -0.00,  0.01,  0.00
-1.86, -0.28, -6.34,  1.00
------
```

**Gives the following picture:**

[image]

```
------   
-0.01,  0.13, -0.99,  0.00
 0.00,  0.99,  0.13,  0.00
 1.00,  0.00, -0.01,  0.00
-1.95, -0.28, -6.31,  1.00
------
```

**Gives the following picture:**
[image]

Note that sign change of 0.01 in column 1 and 3. What does this tell me?

For the normal calculations in GLSL I do the following:

**Vertex shader:**

```
mat4 model_view = view * m;
position_eye = vec3(model_view * vec4(vertex_position, 1.0));
mat3 normal_matrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(model_view)));
normal_eye = normalize(normal_matrix * vertex_normal);
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
 vec3 func_cubemap_reflect()
 {
   vec3 incident_eye = normalize(position_eye);
   vec3 normal = normalize(normal_eye);
   vec3 reflected = reflect(incident_eye, normal);

   // convert from eye to world space
   reflected = vec3(inverse(view) * vec4(reflected, 0.0));
   return texture (cube_texture, reflected).rgb;
  }
```

Any idea how to debug this or resolve it so the reflection are always the "correct way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you're losing precision somewhere in your calculations, possibly the matrix inversion.

Some options:

- Try setting `highp` in your shaders?
- If your GLSL version supports it, you can try defining the `view`/`model_view` matrices as `dmat4` (also for better precision).

Comment: I tried highp without success. However, I am testing an approach where I do `reflected = vec3(inverse(view + mat4(1.0) * 0.01) * vec4(reflected, 0.0));`. That is I'm adding a damping factor to the inversion to stabilize it. Results look as expected now. Not sure how bad this hack is though? Any thoughts?